# Stop UIPanGestureRecognizer from moving UIView vertically when inside a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to have a pan gesture that only moves the UIView horizontally.

So far, at the start of the pan gesture, only horizontal movements are allowed, but **once the
pan gesture has started, the UIView moves both horizontally and vertically**.

- How do I **stop the UIView from moving vertically at all times**?
- Is there any way that the **top of the UIView can always be at the top of the screen**?

i.e. it never moves vertically from its set position

Here is my current code:

```
- (void)panePanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{    
    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            self.paneStartLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mainView];
            self.paneVelocity = 0.0;
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            CGPoint panLocationInPaneView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mainView];
            CGFloat velocity = -(self.paneStartLocation.x - panLocationInPaneView.x);
            CGRect newFrame = self.mainView.frame;

            newFrame.origin.x += (panLocationInPaneView.x - self.paneStartLocation.x);
            if (newFrame.origin.x < 0.0) newFrame.origin.x = 0.0;
            self.mainView.frame = newFrame;

            if (velocity != 0) {
                self.paneVelocity = velocity;
            }
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            [self animate];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see only updates to the mainView frame's origin.x.  Nothing in this code indicates that the y value is changing.  Maybe NSLog(@"%f", self.mainView.frame.origin.y); on state changed?  Let's see if it's changing.

Comment: I checked that and it always says 0 for the origin.y :( @danh

Comment: Also, I don't change the y value in the animate method either, so I am so confused to what's happening. @danh

Comment: So the origin.y is unchanged, and yet you see vertical movement?  The only thing I can think of to explain this is if the view is contained in another view that's moving vertically.

Comment: Yes, mainView is a subview of a Scroll View @danh  With this new info do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @danh I removed the scroll view and it solved this problem, but now the mainView won't scroll and it needs to scroll :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling scrolling on state begun and re-enabling it on state ended.

```
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];    // in case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];   // in case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
```

Comment: Good idea, but it seems to cause interference between the pan gestures and the scroll view which has its own pan gestures, I will work with this idea to see if I can get it to work though @danh

Comment: This works pretty well, with  `if (velocity > 0.0)[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];` in the UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged and `[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];` in UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded @danh

Comment: Glad you got it.  You beat me to it.  I'll post here if I learn anything else useful in the little project I started.

Comment: Ok thanks! This simple, yet effective solution makes my first iOS app that I am currently making, look so much less glitchier! Thanks a lot. @danh  And would be interested to hear about anything you find regarding this with your lil project

Comment: @GangstaGraham - see if there's anything useful in the other answer I provided.

Comment: it's a very sweet, simple solution, but I need to stop the UIView from moving vertically, hence this is a better solution for me, however, that other solution is a better solution for general purposes and other viewers of the site, so thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I did learn a couple things by building this myself.  I think the pan logic can be simplified, and I think it can be made to work without disabling scrolling.

Try this: create a new single-view application project.  Add a scroll view in storyboard.  Add an outlet called 'scrollView' connecting to the ViewController.  In ViewController.m add this code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;  // connected in storyboard
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for (int i=0; i<60; i++) {
        UIView *draggableView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, i*40, 34, 34)];
        draggableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
        [draggableView addGestureRecognizer:pan];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:draggableView];
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 60*40);
}
```

This adds a bunch of draggable views to the scroll view, giving each a pan gesture recognizer.  I made a pan method like yours, except much simpler...

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    switch (gr.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            UIView *view = gr.view;
            CGRect frame = view.frame;

            gr.view.frame = CGRectMake([gr translationInView:view].x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

That's it.  I don't disable scrolling, but we get the behavior that I think you're looking for.  Glad your solution is working, but try out a project like this and see if it tells you anything about what you're up to.

Comment: This is definitely a simpler solution, @danh   however, it does not stop the UIView from moving vertically at all times. Once again, thanks, for your help. :)